# Overwrite doctrine setters when we are using i18n actAs

Tags: symfony1, internationalization, doctrine, setter

I want know if is possible (and how?) overwrite doctrine setters when we use i18n actAs...

I'm trying something like this:

```
class Category extends BaseCategory
{
    /*
     * Overwrite save method
     */
    public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null)
    {
        $conn = $conn ? $conn : $this->getTable()->getConnection();

        $conn->beginTransaction();
        try
        {
            $this->setSlug();

            $ret = parent::save($conn);
            $conn->commit();

            return $ret;
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $conn->rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    public function setSlug()
    {
        $slug = $this->getName() . 'lala lala';
        parent::_set('slug', $slug);
    }
.....
```

But only save the $slug value in one lang (I have 2 languages).

Any Idea??

Thanks A Lot!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for replaying. I solved it like this:

> $cultures =
>   sfConfig::get('app_cultures');
>
> ```
>       // seteamos slug
>       foreach($cultures as $culture)
>       {
>           parent::_set('slug', 'lala lala');
>       } ...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through the translations:

```
foreach($this->Translations as $lang => $t) {
  $t->slug = $t->name.'lala';
}
```